# Install phpmyadmin client on third level domain

Tags: apache, centos

How do change basic url (mysite.com/phpmyadmin) in a third level domain?
I'm just trying to make this by phpMyAdmin.conf file, but doesn't work.

Thanks in advance for every advice.

Comment: The pma configuration has absolutely nothing to do with what subdomains your server “knows” and where it routes them to.

Comment: Ok, is it possible to do it? If yes, How can do it? Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to set pma on a third level domain.
This configuration working on CentOS 7 with apache web server:

- Create db.mysite.com.conf in /etc/httpd/sites-available
- Config your virtul host on your own
- Set "DocumentRoot" to /usr/share/phpMyAdmin
- Create a symbolic link in /etc/httpd/sites-enabled to enable your virtual host
- Restart apache (systemctl restart httpd)

Enjoy! Thanks @CBroe for your "no" answer